# KohanaPHP Controller. Should I group them?

Tags: model-view-controller, controller, kohana

I'm new to OOPHP and frameworks at all.

I'm just wondering...

I have few controllers:
dashboard
signup
login and few more

I've put them into users directory. Everything is working correctly, I'm just wondering if I should put everything in one controller and signup, etc. should be a method of users controller? Or am I doing it correct way?

Regards,
M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's totally up to you. The stuff you currently have could probably all go into one controller (user controller in this case), but it can build up to request the separation you already have, e.g. separate controller for each action, grouped by a prefix.

Good thing about kohana is that it allows you to do stuff like this the way you want to, there isn't a single guideline about putting many 'common' actions into the same controller; do it as you like / find appropriate.